# Amazon web service + iphone tutorials

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services

I tried googling, but didn't have success finding tutorials for 
amazon web service(AWS) with iphone.

I want to learn how to use AWS with iphone.

Please help me out, by providing some tutorials , guidelines etc.

Appreciate it.
Regards

Comment: Are you talking about the web service that provides details of Amazon's products, or about Amazon's cloud computing infrastructure?

Comment: thanks for replying Amorya..i am talking about the one, which provides details of amazon's products....i'll read about the cloud computing after this one gets completes. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they have an SDK for this...

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5127796662758927

Hope this helps, keep me posted if you find anything else..

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't use e Amazon API in an iPhone app:

http://techcrunch.com/2009/07/07/amazon-killing-mobile-apps-that-use-its-data/